# How to change https to http

Tags: http, https

I have my website secured using the verisign ssl protection. I realised that the website takes too much time to load due to the fact the https shows on all the pages. I would like to change this and do it in a such a way to allow the https to show only when people are visiting a particular page. I really don't know how to do this. Any advice would help. Thanks

Comment: Especially with HTTP pipelining, I seriously doubt that simply using HTTPS is causing a noticable delay in your websites operation. How did you determine this was causing issues?

Comment: Thanks for replying Matthew, I realised a delay after the ssl has been installed. Anyway, the client would like it to be available only on a particular page. please any idea?

Comment: If you do a trace on a site loading with SSL using a profiler that gives you the info (e.g. http://www.webpagetest.org/ ) then you can see the HTTPS negotiation overhead - it can be significant on the first request, I've seen close to a second at times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want most of your site to be non-ssl, but want ssl on www.mydomain.com/login, then just make sure any links to the login page specify https:

```
href="https://www.mydomain.com/login"
```

To prevent users typing in the url without the https, and force ssl on a specific page, you could use an .htaccess redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /login https://www.mydomain.com/login
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the issue is that the https shows even when on the index page which does not contain anything sensible. I would like to prevent it from showing when browsing the rest of the pages a part from a particular one. any idea?

Comment: I've never seen that issue myself, but would suspect it has something to do with your server config. Have you got access to your httpd.conf file?